# All data are in parentheses instead of bracket

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

After calling data from API using, `dictonary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary.` My value is always in parentheses. How do change from parentheses to bracket?

Comment: What value? Parenthesis or Square Bracklet, it has a meaning of being either a Dictionary or an Array. You can't change them as you want like that. Also, Swift/Objective-C have different way of showing a Dictionary/Array, what that may be very different of JSON representation. It's just a representation.

Comment: You can convert the data to a json string `[]` instead of `()` but this for viewing only

   **let str = String(data: data, encoding:.utf8)print(str)**

retrieving content of dictionary has no relation to what you want

Comment: ["type": MultiPolygon, "coordinates": <__NSArrayM 0x60c000641410>(
<__NSArrayM 0x60c0006413e0>(
<__NSArrayM 0x60c0006413b0>(
<__NSArrayM 0x60c00045cfe0>(
103.908057506263,
1.30981613450459
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x60c000459a70>(
103.908215431086,
1.30910851741726
)))] I wanted to draw a polygon in google maps. How do I draw with these coordianates?

Comment: @HanafiHisyam Please [edit] your question with all relevant details. Do not post details in comments.

Comment: You need to learn about parsing into custom objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is just an artifact of how Xcode (really lldb) displays dictionaries when debugging.

`["{key}":{value}...]` will be used to display any dictionary.

`({value}...)` will be used to display arrays

The rest of what you see is because the coordinates array is an array(1) of array(1) of array(1) of array(2) with two values  `[[[[Double]]]]`

Mostly you just need to learn to read the debugger output.